# Remover classe dando efeito transição

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho uma classe chamada 'fixed' com um transition nela, quando adiciono essa classe ele faz uma transação, o problema é que quando eu removo essa classe, ela esta sendo removido de forma muito bruta, não sei como proceder para dar um efeito de transação também na saida dessa classe, a classe fixed possui uma transição all linear de 1 segundo:

```
var menu = $('.fixa').offset().top + 10;
var $meuMenu = $('fixa');
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if (menu <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('.fixa').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.fixa').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Isso vai depender da diferência que existe entre o elemento com a class fixed e sem ela. Você pode trabalhar com 2 class, removendo uma e adicionando a outra simultaneamente, sendo uma revertendo a outra. De qualquer forma existe um tutoria no stackoverflow em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509002/css-transition-when-class-removed. Este também explica bem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148876/css3-transition-with-jquery-addclass-and-removeclass

Comment: Já havia pensado em adicionar outra class para remover, mas pensei ter uma forma de eliminar essa opção, acabei por optar em criar outra class mesmo, vlw

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema com teu CSS.
Fiz esse código para testar e funciona OK. http://codepen.io/fernandosavio/pen/xgEvbz